# How to left align widget label in iPython 3?

Tags: widget, alignment, label, jupyter-notebook

How can I left align, rather than right align, the label in an iPython 3 widget, such as IntSlider? My ultimate goal is to left align a set of labeled widgets. This entails left aligning their labels, since the label is the leftmost element of each widget.

I've read the discussion in
[Aligning TextBox Widgets in IPython Notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534123/aligning-textbox-widgets-in-ipython-notebooks), but (a) it focuses on making more space for a right-aligned label, and (b) the proposed solution does not seem to affect the label width. (As an aside, I would be interested in finding cell-executable code that can reset the minimum label width.)

I've also read the discussion in [Change the size of the label in an IPython notebook widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114757/change-the-size-of-the-label-in-an-ipython-notebook-widget), but it doesn't seem to offer a simple solution.

Thanks for your help.

#### Addendum (2015-06-02):

Looks like widget.interactive() does not play nicely with the solution suggested by Jakob. Example:

```py
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display
def mySlider(text='', twidth=100, min=0, max=10, value=5):
    c1 = widgets.HBox()
    ints = widgets.IntSlider(min=min, max=max, value=value)
    text = widgets.HTML(text, width=twidth)
    c1.children = (text, ints)
    return c1

s1 = mySlider('Test')
s2 = mySlider('TestTest')
s3 = mySlider('TestTestTest')

def process(a, b, c):
    print([a, b, c])

widgets.interactive(
    process,
    a=s1.children[1].value,
    b=s2.children[1].value,
    c=s3.children[1].value
)
```

yields slider labels a, b, c with the usual alignment.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply combine an IntSlider with an Html widget to create your custom widget like

```py
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display
def mySlider(text='', twidth=100):
    c1 = widgets.HBox()
    ints = widgets.IntSlider()
    text = widgets.HTML(text, width=twidth)
    c1.children = (text, ints)
    return c1
```

Using this method, some widgets could look like

```py
s1 = mySlider('Test')
s2 = mySlider('TestTest')
s3 = mySlider('TestTestTest')
display(s1,s2,s3)
```

[image]

### Update to work with interact

To use these custom widgets with *interact* it is necessary to add some properties and callbacks. The *interact* method requires the `widget.description` and the `widget.value` arguments to setup the interactive widgets. As our container widget does not have these arguments, they are added manually. Moreover it is necessary to link the `container.value` with the `IntSlider.value`. This is once realized by a simple assignment, and more important via the `on_trait_change` method.
Finally, the interact methods calls the process function on `widget.on_trait_change` callbacks, thus the `container.on_trait_change` method is replaced by the `IntSlider.on_trait_change` call.
The updated code looks like:

```py
def mySlider2(text='', twidth=100, min=0, max=10, value=5):
    c1 = widgets.HBox()
    ints = widgets.IntSlider(min=min, max=max, value=value)
    text = widgets.HTML(text, width=twidth)
    c1.children = (text, ints)
    c1.description = text
    c1.value = ints.value
    def update(name, value):
        c1.value = value
    ints.on_trait_change(update,'value')
    c1.on_trait_change = ints.on_trait_change
    return c1

s1a = mySlider2('Test')
s2a = mySlider2('TestTest')
s3a = mySlider2('TestTestTest')

widgets.interactive(
    process,
    a=s1a,
    b=s2a,
    c=s3a
)
```